# Traffic disappears from one server to another when routed through VPN

Tags: linux, vpn

In the following setup when I try to send a ping from host 'a' over VPN to host 'c', I see it being received on host b's tun0 interface and forwarded on eth0, but then it disappears. I don't see anything coming into host c's eth0 interface. The net result is that pings are not answered back. I can ping host c from host b directly(where source ip address shows up within the subnet where host b and c are located, host a has different range (10.8.0.0/16)).

How do I debug this? What could be the issues? How do I detect whether the traffic was send out by the hardware or not? (Could it be blocked out by linux firewall?)

Setup:

Host(a)  -> VPN(b) -> host to be pinged(c)

host a has eth0 interface 
host b has tun0 and eth0 interface. 
host c has eth0 interface.

Evidence:

```
on host a's tun0 interface 

> sudo tcpdump -i tun0 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo or icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echoreply'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
05:09:36.878793 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.146.8: ICMP echo request, id 3497, seq 611, length 64
05:09:37.884830 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.146.8: ICMP echo request, id 3497, seq 612, length 64


On host b's eth0 interface 

> sudo tcpdump -i eth0 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo or icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echoreply'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:07:43.991961 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.146.8: ICMP echo request, id 3497, seq 499, length 64
05:07:44.997944 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.146.8: ICMP echo request, id 3497, seq 500, length 64

on host c's eth0 interface

> sudo tcpdump -i eth0 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo or icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echoreply'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
<no output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out after a few hours of investigation.

The problem is with the forwarding setup. 
The packets forwarded to eth0 port does not have correct source ip address of the host within the network. The ip addressis from VPN.

```
05:07:43.991961 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.146.8: ICMP echo request, id 3497, seq 499, length 64
```

You can switch that by enabling equivalent of NAT (on routers) in linux OS:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <eth0 or whatever else> -j MASQUERADE
```

This fixed the issue for me.